# How to add multiple IPv6 addresses to an interface in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ipv6, netsh

I can add addresses to an interface using

```
netsh interface ipv6 add address SomeInterface SomeIPv6Address
```

Can I somehow add a range of ipv6 addresses e.g. `2001:db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001` to `2001:db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a loop and add individual IP addresses. Here's how it can be done in PowerShell

```powershell
1..0xFFFF |% { netsh interface ipv6 add address Interface ("2001:db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:{0:x4}" -f $_) }
```

In cmd it'll be much trickier (and much slower)

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1, 1, 65535) do (
    call :tohex %%i
    netsh interface ipv6 add address SomeInterface 2001:db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:!hex:~-4!
)
exit

:tohex
call cmd /c exit /b %1
set hex=%=exitcode%
goto :eof
```

But the question is **why do you want to bind so many addresses to a single interface?**